# Является ли использования макроса в данной ситуации хорошим подходом

Tags: c++, макросы, хороший-тон

Доброго времени суток. Имеется две перегрузки операторов для моего класса, соответствие типов параметров тем, для которых поддерживается оператор, проверяется с помощью дополнительного типа в шаблоне и `enable_if`, и шапка шаблона получается одинаковой для двух функций:

```
#define TEMPLATE_T1_T2_WITH_PARAM_TYPE_CHECK template<typename T1, typename T2,\
        class = typename std::enable_if<\
            (std::is_same<T1, dstring>::value ||\
            std::is_same<typename std::remove_extent<T1>::type, char>::value &&\
            std::is_array<T1>::value) &&\
            (std::is_same<T2, dstring>::value ||\
            std::is_same<typename std::remove_extent<T2>::type, char>::value &&\
            std::is_array<T2>::value)\
        >::type>

    TEMPLATE_T1_T2_WITH_PARAM_TYPE_CHECK
    friend dstring operator+(const T1& lhs, const T2& rhs){
        dstring res(lhs);
        res += rhs;
        return res;
    }


    TEMPLATE_T1_T2_WITH_PARAM_TYPE_CHECK
    friend bool operator!=(const T1& lhs, const T2& rhs){
        return !(lhs == rhs);
    }
```

Вопрос следующий: является ли объявление шапки шаблона макросом адекватным и приемлемым выходом в данной ситуации, или же лучше будет продублировать код? Все-таки многие не советуют использовать макросы, и в данном случае это могло бы привести к проблемам с отладкой.

П.С. И является ли вообще перегрузка оператора для разных комбинаций нескольких типов приемлемой в виде шаблона, или же лучше создать обычную перегрузку для каждого случая с одинаковым телом, вроде `dstring + dstring`, `dstring + char*`, `char* + dstring`, и.т.д. ?

Comment: Выглядит как комбинаторный взрыв. Для каждой пары типов приводимых к `dstring` будет создан экземпляр каждой функции. Может быть, подумать про `operator dstring()`?

Comment: @user58697, в данном случае интерфейс обязывает иметь именно перегрузки этих операторов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Макросы - плохо.
Избежать дублирования условий можно например так:

```
template<typename T1> 
struct is_compatible : std::integral_constant< bool,
    ( std::is_same<T1, dstring>::value ||
      std::is_same<typename std::remove_extent<T1>::type, char>::value &&
      std::is_array<T1>::value
    )>
{};
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct enabled_if_compatible : std::enable_if< 
           is_compatible<T1>::value 
        && is_compatible<T2>::value
        , void >
{};

template<typename T1, typename T2,
         class = typename enabled_if_compatible<T1,T2>::type >
friend dstring operator+(const T1& lhs, const T2& rhs){
    dstring res(lhs);
    res += rhs;
    return res;
}    

template<typename T1, typename T2,
         class = typename enabled_if_compatible<T1,T2>::type >
friend bool operator!=(const T1& lhs, const T2& rhs){
    return !(lhs == rhs);
}
```